# mplfinance KeyError: 'Open'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create OHLC charts from tick data using *mplfinance* from a *pandas* dataframe. The original data is stored in a database containing `date` (fecha), `time` (hora) and `last`, so, before tryging to create the chart I have to resample to OHLC.

```
cur = conn.cursor()
nameddict=({"ticker": "GFGC90.0JU"})
select="""SELECT 
    EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (fecha || ' ' || hora)::timestamp) as datetime, last from preciosrt
    where ticker=%(ticker)s and last is not null 
    """
df = pandas.read_sql_query(select, conn, params=nameddict)
df['datetime'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['datetime'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('datetime')
ohlc = df.resample('5Min').ohlc()
print(ohlc)
mpf.plot(ohlc)
```

As you can see, the resulting dataframe contains the desired result:

```
                     last                   
                     open  high   low  close
datetime                                    
2020-05-04 16:15:00  5.10  5.10  5.10  5.100
2020-05-04 16:20:00  5.14  5.14  5.02  5.140
2020-05-04 16:25:00  5.00  5.25  5.00  5.249
2020-05-04 16:30:00  5.29  5.45  5.29  5.450
2020-05-04 16:35:00  5.45  5.50  5.30  5.300
2020-05-04 16:40:00  5.21  5.30  5.20  5.200
2020-05-04 16:45:00  5.20  5.30  5.20  5.200
2020-05-04 16:50:00  5.21  5.30  5.21  5.260
2020-05-04 16:55:00  5.26  5.33  5.10  5.100
```

But, when I try to plot the chart using `mpf.plot(ohlc)` I get this error:

```
...

~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Open'
```

How can I solve this?.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, I think mpf is very particular in what the columns are named, try renaming the columns and the index using:

```
df.columns = ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
df.index.name = "Date"
```